# ES index not appearing in Kibana "Create index pattern"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Trying to set up my first ELK stack and I can't seem to get Kibana to recognize my index.

I am using ElasticSearch 6.x

Using `curl -XGET -u elastic:mysupersecurepasswordofcourse "http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v" -H 'Content-Type: application/json'` I get:

```
health status index                           uuid                   pri rep 
docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   .monitoring-es-6-2018.02.17     Fjh6Wk-RSMW-jCmMXbPexg   1   0      
37758           72     27.4mb         27.4mb
green  open   .security-6                     grVz87fZQ6GBsTvl9TXRUw   1   0          
3            0      9.9kb          9.9kb
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-6-2018.02.17 d0tKI_50RfCaALx3hYtnHw   1   0       
3056            0      1.6mb          1.6mb
green  open   .watcher-history-7-2018.02.17   KD1SdjJ0QHCmGnarHq9y2A   1   0       
3532            0      7.7mb          7.7mb
green  open   .kibana                         TgCs4oAdRsandc3US1haxw   1   0          
2            0     13.2kb         13.2kb
green  open   .monitoring-alerts-6            xuTWxQIlTIawPJGSCiZNYA   1   0          
4            0     23.9kb         23.9kb
green  open   .triggered_watches              JBQvWNh8ShG-M795rNKA4Q   1   0          
2          124    348.2kb        348.2kb
yellow open   tick                            6IlSo9exRe2V350wXfEvJA   5   1          
3            0       16kb           16kb
green  open   .watches                        Www6IbiaRPGOWcJMj0zmjw   1   0          
6            0    101.4kb        101.4kb
```

`tick` is what I'm trying to get to show up in kibana.

I can do this: `curl -XGET -u elastic:superstrong "http://localhost:9200/tick/_doc/tIBvpWEBbXT5kQhPxkTg?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json'` and get back what I expect - a single document.

This setup does have xpack installed, and I have ensured that the `elasticsearch.username` and `elasticsearch.password` have been set.  I'm not sure if it's related, but if I attempt to do PUT/POST from the Kibana dev console I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user [kibana]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "security_exception",
    "reason": "action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user [kibana]"
  },
  "status": 403
}
```

That error message *seems* useful but googling has turned up nothing.  To further complicate things, If I run `GET _cat/indices` from Dev console I do get the same results as I have on the CLI.

So, how do I get Kibana to show me the documents that are in the `tick` index?

Edit: I'll also note that I am visiting **app/kibana#/management/kibana/index?_g=()** to attempt to create the index; however, I see `Couldn't find any Elasticsearch data`.  If I click on `Check for new data` I don't get any errors, but nothing is found.  If I check the box, `Include system indices` I see 4 of the 8 included in the output above: `.kibana`, `.monitoring-alerts-6`, `.monitoring-es-6-2018.02.17`, `.monitoring-kibana-6-2018.02.17`

Edit2: I do see now that if I click `Check for new data` I get a JS error in the console `Error: Minified React error #200; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.`.

Comment: Try disabling xpack security pack and try again, the error is related to user permissions only, which might not be setup correctly. Regarding React error you can ignore it, it is just related to minified and non-minified JS.

Answer (score 2):

You have to grant Kibana user the access to the tick index, editing the kibana role. By default the kibana user has access only to the .kibana index (where visualize and dashbords are stored).

Alternatively, create an other user with all privileges on both the tick index and .kibana or use directly the super user elastic that by default have access to all the indexes.